# Discord Bot set up on Vultr VPS Ubuntu 64 that gets started with nohup command goes offline every few hours

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, vps

I made a very basic ping pong Discord bot with a few commands.

I deployed it on Vultr VPS server. I followed this tutorial: https://www.writebots.com/discord-bot-hosting/

PM2 did not make my bot go online, so that's where I differed from the tutorial. I kick it off with command:

`nohup node bot.js`

It runs fine for hours and then goes offline several hours later. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Could you please include the code you are using?

Comment: Can you explain why PM2 wasn't working? I use it to manage a lot of my bots, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using NoHup with the vps I think you should simply make a screen session and then detach it before you close the terminal.